# How to get source codes recursively using inspect?

Tags: python

Suppose we have a python function named `some_func`.

I know `inspect.getsource(some_func)` can get this function's source code.

But how can we get all functions source codes which called by this `some_func`, in case we only use `some_func` instance (i.e. we don't to view the code of `some_func` manually, and pick the called function names to run the `inspect.getsource` ).

So, that is how to write a method named `get_all_source_code_recursively`, and we can use it to process this `some_func`: `get_all_source_code_recursively(some_func)`

Comment: Can you add an example for the code and the output you expect get_all_source_code_recursively to show?

Comment: You'd have to call the function

Comment: @Ron Serruya For example, the result is a dict, its key is the function with module name, and the value is the source code.